# Which web server should http security headers be used in when web application is a consumer of a web service?

Tags: http, security, web, service, header

There is a web application and a web service. These are in separate web servers. Web application is a consumer of web service.

The questions is which web server should http security headers (e.g. Strict-Transport-Layer, X-XSS-Protection, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, etc.) be used in?

In web service's web server or web application's web server that is consumer, or both of them as dual use? Which one is reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

If you understand what each of them do, you will be able to tell which is needed where.

`Strict-Transport-Security` is about ensuring that clients only use https (and not plain http) to access content. This of course needs a compliant client. All browsers are like that, and hopefully some other clients also consider this header. Even if not, you should just send it from both services and webapps.

`X-XSS-Protection` is about explicitly enabling some cross-site-scripting protection in browsers (this practically means not running javascript on a page where the request contained the same javascript, to prevent some reflected XSS). It is still the best practice to send this for web apps, though it is now the default in browsers, and this does not really prevent more advanced XSS at all (the app itself needs to be correctly implemented). For backend services that only serve `text/json` and **not** `text/html`, this is irrelevant, also it it irrelevant if the client is not a browser (but for example a webapp). You can still send it from services too, it won't do any harm.

`X-Frame-Options` is to mitigate clickjacking among some other more niche attacks. It basically prevents the browser from opening the page in a frame. If the client is not a browser, this doesn't make a lot of sense, however, this might have implications on data leaks if used together with CORS headers. So again, you can just send this from services too, but not strictly necessary in the base case.

`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` is to mitigate an attack that used to performed against older versions of Internet Explorer (and maybe some other browsers as well) where they incorrectly determined file types and sent content type accordingly, especially during file downloads. I think this is no longer feasible with modern browsers, but the best practice is to still send this. It has no effect for non-browser clients, but does no harm either.

So in short, most of these are only relevant for web applications, and not backend services that do not serve html. However, you can and probably should still send these from services too, they will just do nothing in most cases, and might help when for example an attacker make a user open a service response in a browser somehow.

Comment: More specifically, does http security headers are only for web browsers or can be for desktop or mobile app? If desktop or mobile app understand this directives when web service / web api server respond security headers, then I will say SOAP and REST web services / web apis can make use of http security header avantages. Shortly http security headers are just for web browsers? Or these are also for other consumer applications?

Comment: Also in a web vulnerability scanner website, they introduce http security headers as "they re for client (usually for web browser)" in their article (ref: https://www.invicti.com/blog/web-security/http-security-headers/) If other clients can understand these security headers then result is being backend web services and web apis should use them? Am I wrong?